# Illegal mix of collation in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, collation

I have been trying to implement emoji in table. I have changed the column collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and the rest of the columns collation are empty but when I try to query out that. I get an error like so

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `qa_defect_comments` where `defect_id` = 2957 and `logged_user_id` = 2 and `comments` = )

Can we set the collation during querying out the data?

EDIT- 
SHOW CREATE TABLE qa_defect_comments

```
CREATE TABLE `qa_defect_comments` (
 `comments_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `defect_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `comments` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `logged_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `assign_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`comments_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1793 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';

```
character_set_client - utf8mb4
character_set_connection - utf8mb4
character_set_database - latin1
character_set_filesystem - binary
character_set_results - utf8mb4
character_set_server - latin1
character_set_system - utf8
character_sets_dir - /usr/share/percona-server/charsets/
```

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';

```
collation_connection - utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database - latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server - latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE qa_defect_comments` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`

Comment: I have edited and added the requested data - @RickJames

Answer (score 3):

Check `config/database.php`.  I think you will find a `utf8` in one or two places, where you should have utf8mb4.

```
'mysql' => [..., 'charset' => 'utf8mb4', 'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', ...]
```

Comment: Is there any way of not changing the config files and still be able to do it?

Comment: Immediately after connecting, use `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.  If it needs a collation, too; see the manual for how to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.
I resolved it by:

1. Navigating to phpMyadmin
2. Select the database your application is using
3. Click on Operations
4. Select Collation: utf8_general_ci
5. Click on Go

Flushed the laravel configuration cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```